# How to find proper value of android:name to resolve "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to work with dynamically added fragments.
My 2 fragments are called: library_view and controls_view and main_layout.xml is the main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fragmentstest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My main class is MainActivity.java. I have the Android Private Libraries option checked.

```
import com.example.fragmentstest.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        //add fragments programatically

        //ref to frag manager
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.present_activity_fragment, new LibraryActivity());
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.select_fragment, new SelectActivity());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

I used android:name in `<activity>` as it came up in auto-suggets but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Also tried unsuccessfully:

- .MainActivity
- com.example.fragmentstest.MainActivity

So my question is, how do I determine the exact value of the android:name field?

MainActivity class in my code extends Activity and two fragments extend the Fragments class.

This is the error log:

```
07-04 19:00:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(18127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.fragmentstest.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.fragmentstest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/data/app/com.example.fragmentstest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.fragmentstest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: is MainActivity declared inside com/example/fragmentstest ?

Comment: Use `.MainActivity` or your second variant.

Comment: @deathember I have alreay tried those two variants, neither worked.

Comment: I do not think that word means what you think it means...  There is nothing in this code that has anything to do with fragments.

Comment: @G. Blake Meike , although I am new to android development, I do know what it means. The MainActivity class programatically includes the fragments (2 of them to create the main activity) by following the 4 steps of referencing the fragment manager, starting the transaction, adding fragments and committing them. If I have misunderstood the concept, please correct me.

Comment: @codename Cool.  I suggest including the code that is the problem, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must mention your package name in the first line in your activity code
like this

```
package com.SHINE.ui;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Mapactivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        TranslationListner, OnTouchListener {
```

here my code in XML manifest is

```
<activity
            android:name="com.SHINE.ui.Mapactivity"
```

Comment: Oh, got it, I had forgotten to mention the package in my java classes.
If you could modify your answer to say that, I will be happy to select it. Thanks for pointing it out indirectly!

Comment: Hey, just for some more accuracy, name = MainActivity also works, so maybe you could just include tell about the part regarding the package in your answer. Thanks again..

Comment: "it's included "you must mention your package name in the first line

Comment: I mean to say that there is no need to change `<activity android:name="MainActivity"`, it works without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: As I said, I have already tried .MainActivity but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you tell us in which package your Activity is ?

Comment: I have my class files in the (default) package... moved them to the com.example.fragmentstest package and was able to get it working!